# passing query string value from asp.net page to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net page with a textbox and a button. on button click, I open a popup and load a page in it using iframe. I want to pass value of textbox as query string to page in iframe. How can I do this?

I tried using server side iframe like this:

```
<iframe id="popupframe" runat="server" src="~/temp.aspx" width="100%" height="455">
            </iframe>
```

but temp.aspx doesnt load and gives 404. If I use it without server side tag

```
<iframe id="popupframe"  src="../../../../temp.aspx" width="100%" height="455">
            </iframe>
```

Page loads in iframe but I can't pass valuue of textbox to temp.aspx. Please suggest solution. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is temp.aspx definitely at the root of your site? A 404 error is normally a pretty clear indication that the thing that you're looking for isn't there! And the fact that you've got a relative path in the working plain HTML version makes me think there might be an issue with your server-side version's path.

As an alternative, you could pass a querystring to your popup page and use some javascript on that page to manipulate the src property of the iframe.

e.g. (script on popup page)

```
var qs = window.location.search; // Gets the entire querystring - not very obvious!
var iframe = document.getElementById("popupframe");
iframe.src += qs; // Adds the querystring on to the end of the iframe's src.
```

You'd want to run that after the page content has loaded. I don't know if you're using jQuery or some other framework (or no framework!) so I won't go into how to do that (but can if you need me to).

Comment: yes temp.aspx is at the root of page and ~/temp.aspx is not working. where as popup is 4 levels deeper.

Comment: I want to do it server side. If I want to do it using javascript, Do I need to add above js code to page where popup is being loaded or to the page which opens in popup ?

Comment: sorry, i don't want to come across as really nit-picking but you've written "is at the root of page", which is ambiguous since it's the root of the *site* that's important. Just to put my mind at rest, can you confirm that if you enter "your.site.com/temp.aspx" into your browser you get that test page?

Comment: you'd put that javascript in the page that pops up when you click the button. I'm assuming that your structure is: PageWithButton->(popup)->PageWithIFrame->(contains)->temp.aspx.

Comment: that is odd! have you tried without the tilde (i.e. just "/temp.aspx") in the iframe src?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15964/discussion-between-jon-and-dotnetsparrow)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<iframe id="popupframe" runat="server" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/temp.aspx") %>" width="100%" height="455">
            </iframe>
```

Comment: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Comment: my bad, missed your runat='server'. Make it a regular html iframe, then. There's no good reason for it to have the runat tag.

Comment: Look at what's rendered in the markup, does it make sense?  Make sure you can navigate to the page normally, perhaps there's an issue that is occurring that has nothing to do w/ the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I used this

Codebehid on button Click Event

this.iframRfer.Attributes["src"] = "visit_opd_refer.aspx?regnn="+opdNo;
   mpopup.Show();

Answer (score -1):

```
 <% Int64 ss =Convert.ToInt64( Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());%>
 <% string bb = ss.ToString().Insert(0, "testing.aspx?id="); %>
  <iframe    src="<%=bb %>"   style="height: 100%; width: 100%; border: 2px;"> 
 </iframe>
```

No need any scripts .This is also kind of format.